# Attask - Pass backslash (\) in URL as value

Tags: attask

I am trying to pass set of values which has backslash("\") in them. This breaks the URL. The URL I submit is `https://{mycompany}.attasksandbox.com/attask/api/project?ID=57ba84---1&updates={"description":"ToImplementWorkFront","URL":"T:%5CTechnologyWorkRequests%5C2016%5CTAD160888_Communications"}&apiKey=g--t&method=put`

I basically want to pass values to URL field as `"URL": "T:\TechnologyWorkRequests\2016\TAD160888_Communications"`

I understand backslash is an unsafe character and hence encoded as %5C as well as %255C-  but I get JSON parsing error. **I am able to pass** a forward slash(/) encoding it as %2F but I am not able to pass "\" character. Can any one please help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this kind of task you should use `POST` instead of `GET` method.
If you still want to use `GET` you can do something like following example:

```
"https://posturl/?update=" + encodeURIComponent("{ \"path\": \"C:\\Windows\\System32\"}")
```

More safe:

```
var data = {
    "path": "C:\\Windows\\System32\"
}
var url = "https://posturl/?update=" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(data))
```

Comment: Daniel - I have never used GET, but rather used PUT as per REST principle. I use .Net framework and it has functions to encode and decode URLs. But the question is, how the API is designed to accept such requests? Once I know the way it should be passed, I can handle it from my c# code.

Comment: If you use put then you should put the data in the request body not in url. 
If you are using dot net webApi it should be declared like this:

`[HttpPut]
public Result Update([FromBody] UpdateData data) `

Backslashes doesn't affect how Json data is parsed as long as you don't care about it when you encode the data. In C#: `var data = JsonConverter.Serialize(updateData);` then you send it in the body of put not in the URL.
I have a suggestion, if you are writing restful API you should take a look at Swagger tool. It's very useful.

Comment: Daniel - Thanks for you comments, but my question is more specific to attask API. I am consuming the API from .Net application using webclient which is trivial in this context. At first place I should understand how API is designed to accept "\" char as a value. Once I have that info, I can pass request in the desired format. I am looking for answers specific to attask API.